# Android private key issues.

Tags: android, private-key

i developed a app in android and released a first version. but now i lost my previous (private key)debug.keystore . Now im going to release a second version with a different private key. but this second version didn't install in phone. how can i resolve this problem? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will have to uninstall the old version and then install the new one, as Android doesn't allow updates to be installed if they have a different signature.

Additionally, all of your users will have to do the same, and App stores like Google Play won't allow you to use an update signed with a different key. You will have to publish your app again under a different package name.

Answer (score 1):

Just change your `Package Name` and change that in `androidManifest` file also and Upload with new `KeyStore`. No other way. Because google won't allow you to upload another application having same `Package name`.